# My pet has a superficial wound on his foot. He's limping. How can I relieve his pain and cover the wound from infection?

Tags: dogs, medicines, injury

I took [my Weimaraners, Cain and Abel](https://www.instagram.com/itscainitsabel/) for a late night walk last night. Not sure how but Abel hurt himself. He has a wound on his front, left leg and a slight limp. Don't want to wrap it with anything as I know he will have ripped it off the second I leave him to his own devices.

What can I do to help him:

1. Not infect the wound as he most definitely will from walking around
2. Cover it so that he does not experience any pain and the wound does
   not get dirt and bacteria on it?

Thanks!

Comment: Clean the wound with soap and water or an anti-bacterial.

Answer (score 1):

If your dog is limping, it is not a small thing. He could be cut in a sensitive area. I would clean the wound with some soap and water and then hydrogen peroxide. I would put an antibacterial on wound and maybe wrap it if dirt would get in the wound. Then I would put a cone collar on him until it healed. That would prevent him from licking it.